# Apple Developer Center - Can't select "App Store and Ad Hoc Production Certificate"

Tags: ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program

I just tried to generate an `App Store and Ad Hoc Production Certificate` for my iPhone app but the radio button can't be selected. (it worked yesterday though)
Does anybody know if there are any known issues with the Developer Center or how to fix this problem?

Screenshot:
[image: The radio button is greyed out]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a maximum of 3 Ad Hoc certificates active at a time. In order to add another one you must revoke a previous certificate.

Comment: Can I use the same iOS Certificate (Production) to sign different apps?

Comment: yes, same ios certificate could b used to sign different apps.